# Remove rows from an R dataframe based on parts of a character variable

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has in the first column a variable (type: character) and some rows start with "#". But there are other words in the variable (lets say: "# AA". I want to delete the rows in which the variable of the first column starts with #. I am not finding a way to do that. Any suggestions?

An example of data would be:

```
mydata = as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c("AA", "AB", "BA", "BB", "--"), 7200, replace = T),
+                        nrow = 600, ncol = 12))
mydata$V1 = as.character(mydata$V1)
mydata$V1 = ifelse(mydata$V1 == "AA", "# AA",mydata$V1)
head(mydata)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try searching for the character at the beginning of each element in the first column, then subsetting with that index:

```
head(mydata[-grep("^#", mydata$V1),])
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12
# 2 -- BB AB -- -- BB AB AB AA  BB  AA  BB
# 3 AB BB AB AB -- -- BA AA AA  BB  BB  AA
# 4 -- AA AB BB BA BB AB BA BA  AB  --  BB
# 5 AB BA AB BA BB AB BA BB BB  AA  BB  BA
# 6 BA AA -- AB BB -- BA BB AB  AB  BB  --
# 7 AB BA BA AA BB BB BA BB AA  BB  BB  BA
```

Comment: Could also test equality against substring(x,1,1)